# Access to the Gmail unique message ID through Java Mail

Tags: groovy, jakarta-mail, imap, gmail-api

I am trying to get the unique message ID through JavaMail, so that I can identify mail without the context of a particular IMAP-folder later. The code I've written so far is as follows:

```
def fp = new FetchProfile()

fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE)
fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.FLAGS)
fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.CONTENT_INFO)
fp.add(javax.mail.UIDFolder.FetchProfileItem.UID)
fp.add("X-mailer")
fp.add("X-GM-MSGID") // Attribute for retrieving the ID in the fetch (?)

uIDFolder.fetch(iMAPmessages, fp);

iMAPmessages.each { msg ->
   println msg.dump()
}
```

Which results in the following output (for one message):

```
<com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage@14c04449 
  bs=com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.BODYSTRUCTURE@5ac31f43
  envelope=com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.ENVELOPE@40399642 
  items=[:] 
  receivedDate=Mon Jul 28 12:18:38 MSK 2014 
  size=3147 
  peek=false 
  uid=991 
  modseq=-1  
  sectionId=null 
  type=null 
  subject=null   
  description=null 
  headersLoaded=false 
  loadedHeaders=[X-GM-MSGID:X-GM-MSGID, X-MAILER:X-mailer] 
  dh=null 
  content=null 
  contentStream=null 
  headers=javax.mail.internet.InternetHeaders@4b7e7ff
  flags=com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.FLAGS@20 
  modified=false 
  saved=true 
  cachedContent=null 
  strict=true 
  msgnum=372 
  expunged=false 
  folder=INBOX 
  session=javax.mail.Session@4f0dc86c>
```

The Envelope:

```
<com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.ENVELOPE@34ea0af2 
  msgno=371 
  date=Sun Jul 27 17:46:08 MSK 2014 
  subject=Re: Require 
  from=[From <from@gmail.com>]
  sender=[sender <sender@gmail.com>] 
  replyTo=[From <from@gmail.com>] 
  to=[receiver <receiver@gmail.com>, =?ISO-8859-1?Q?Johan_W=E4ngl=F6f?= <example@gmail.com>] 
  cc=null 
  bcc=null 
  inReplyTo=<CAHr+Gay-ZX0U-pFuwQUMziyECTOVrLNn-XLtc643DYXwgtdDFQ@mail.gmail.com>
  messageId=<CAHr+GawnCxaT476K8Rm1MeQNPx8HOfL+VqM0ThMydfTNR12rBg@mail.gmail.com>>
```

The last attribute added to the fetch profile is the special attribute to fetch the unique ID (https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions#access_to_the_gmail_unique_message_id_x-gm-msgid).

The messages contains no unique message ID, as far as I can tell. Am I doing something completely wrong?

**Trace of the IMAP Session**

```
* 372 FETCH (UID 991 RFC822.SIZE 3147 INTERNALDATE "28-Jul-2014 08:18:38 +0000" FLAGS (\Seen) ENVELOPE ("Mon, 28 Jul 2014 10:18:38 +0200" "Hej du" (("Emil Tholin" NIL "emtholin" "gmail.com")) (("Emil Tholin" NIL "emtholin" "gmail.com")) (("Emil Tholin" NIL "emtholin" "gmail.com")) (("Emil Tholin" NIL "emtholin" "gmail.com")) NIL NIL NIL "<CADsZLRxveuyQX5gXVHvr8ca57yCLopJEc+TpuL2GS-57Kq+yqg@mail.gmail.com>") BODYSTRUCTURE ((("TEXT" "PLAIN" ("CHARSET" "UTF-8") NIL NIL "7BIT" 13 1 NIL NIL NIL)("TEXT" "HTML" ("CHARSET" "UTF-8") NIL NIL "7BIT" 34 1 NIL NIL NIL) "ALTERNATIVE" ("BOUNDARY" "001a11c1250ef810aa04ff3c91b5") NIL NIL)("TEXT" "PLAIN" ("CHARSET" "US-ASCII" "NAME" "rygg.txt") NIL NIL "BASE64" 2138 0 NIL ("ATTACHMENT" ("FILENAME" "rygg.txt")) NIL) "MIXED" ("BOUNDARY" "001a11c1250ef810af04ff3c91b7") NIL NIL) BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (X-mailer X-GM-MSGID)] {4}
)
A4 OK Success
A5 CLOSE
A5 OK Returned to authenticated state. (Success)
DEBUG IMAPS: added an Authenticated connection -- size: 1
specificFolderHeaders() - Closing the mail connection
A6 LOGOUT
* BYE LOGOUT Requested
A6 OK 73 good day (Success)
DEBUG IMAPS: IMAPStore connection dead
DEBUG IMAPS: IMAPStore cleanup, force false
DEBUG IMAPS: IMAPStore cleanup done
```

Comment: include the output of msg.dump...

Comment: Is there any reason that the standard (not gmail-only) `messageID` is not sufficient?

Comment: @djechlin Certainly, it slipped my mind. Thanks.

Comment: @hsan Yeah, to retrieve the mail strictly from the Gmail API, the messageID is not sufficient (to my knowledge). https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get

Comment: @Tholle Right. Seems like the API needs Gmail's own ID for retrieval. At least on that test page it does not work with the messageID. Java Mail however can access and search (with `messageIDTerm`) for the messageID even in gmail accounts.

Comment: @hsan You are correct. The point with all this is so that we can get an id compatible with the Gmail API so we can download attachments etc. directly from the client side. I know that what I am asking for is possible, but I fail to see where I mess up.

Comment: next up, can you post the trace of your IMAP session? (specifically the fetch request/response) I believe -Djava.mail.debug=true

Comment: What I can gather from [this](http://www.yoxel.com/blog/latest-by-date-and-by-id/) is that it cannot be done with the regular FetchProfile. In the linked entry Gmail's custom properties are retrieved using `doCommand` after the regular fetch.

Comment: @djechlin Sure. Done.

Comment: @hsan You are probably right. This looks interesting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Gmail-specific APIs](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/gimap/package-summary.html) in the [latest release of JavaMail](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Download_JavaMail_1.5.2_Release).

Answer (score 1):

Bill hit the nail on the head, but I just thought I'd share the minor issues I faced.

The code I posted in my question didn't change much:

```
def messages = []

def fp = new FetchProfile()
fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE)
fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.FLAGS)
fp.add(javax.mail.UIDFolder.FetchProfileItem.UID)
fp.add("X-mailer")

//Google specific attributes
fp.add(GmailFolder.FetchProfileItem.MSGID)
fp.add(GmailFolder.FetchProfileItem.THRID)

uIDFolder.fetch(iMAPmessages, fp);

iMAPmessages.each { msg ->
  GmailMessage gmsg = (GmailMessage) msg
  println Long.toHexString(gmsg.getMsgId().toLong()) //Eureka!
}
```

The part that took some time to get right was to connect to gimap with an authorization token properly:

```
def connect(mailAccount) {

  if (mailAccount.provider == "Gmail") {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.store.protocol", "gimaps");
    props.put("mail.gimaps.sasl.enable", "true"); // Note the "gimaps"
    props.put("mail.gimaps.sasl.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
    props.put(OAuth2SaslClientFactory.OAUTH_TOKEN_PROP, mailAccount.token);
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

    final String emptyPassword = ""; // Since we authorize with token
    GmailStore store = (GmailStore) session.getStore("gimaps");
    store.connect(
        "imap.gmail.com",
        993,
        mailAccount.emailAddress,
        emptyPassword);
    return store;
  }
  else {
    OAuth2Authenticator.initialize();
    def store = OAuth2Authenticator.connectToImap(
        "imap.gmail.com",
        993,
        mailAccount.emailAddress,
        mailAccount.token,
        false); // Debug flag

    return store;
  }
}
```

Using a separate store for the Gmail-addresses and the neat OAuth2Authenticator (https://code.google.com/p/google-mail-oauth2-tools/source/browse/trunk/java/com/google/code/samples/oauth2/OAuth2Authenticator.java?r=3) for other providers worked great.